# Sense of the graph of a function

Tags: functions, definition

What makes it necessary to define the graph of a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ as $$\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in A\}$$
which makes it a subset of $A\times B$, when this is *equal to the function itself*, which is defined to be a left-unique and left-defined relation from $A$ to $B$ — and thus a subset of $A\times B$, *too*?

**EDIT:**
I disagree that with this set-based approach information about the domain and range would get lost, because as I perceived it, there is no definition of a “function”, but rather of a “function from A to B”, in mathematical terms: $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B:\Leftrightarrow f$ is a relation between $A$ and $B \land \forall a\in A\exists! b\in B: (a,b)\in f$.

If we now want to construct some definitions regarding functions, we do not write “Let $f\subset A\times B$”, but rather write “let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$”. This makes by definition $f\subset A\times B$, but also preserves the additional information as the domain etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying the graph with the function is a common approach in set theory, especially elementary set theory. It is awkward in other disciplines, where it is more convenient for a function to be a special kind of object which can have properties that are specific to functions (continuity, for example).

A case of this from topology is that if $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces, then the graph of a function can be naturally made into a topological space (it has the subspace topology inherited from the product topology on $A \times B$). So now by making this identification we are saying that a topological space and a function are the same object, which is confusing at best. Similar problems occur in algebra or indeed anywhere where the product has more than just its set-theoretic structure.

Another problem is that the graph does not have the domain conveniently "stored"; it has to be extracted from the projection, whereas the domain of a function is usually regarded as an inherent attribute of the function. Even worse, the codomain isn't accessible from the graph at all; the best way one could define the codomain from the graph would be to identify it with the image. This would be a problem for defining surjectivity and related notions.

Comment: I do not see any conflicts. I think I somehow get your points, but I need some concrete example in which you use my definition trying to define something like continuity (or even something more trivial) and point out where the formal / logical issue is.
Anyway, how would you define a function differently?

Comment: Looking at the topology example, I think it should be apparent that the *function* $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$, $f(x)=x$ is not really the same as the diagonal $\{ (x,x) : x \in [0,1] \}$. The former is a continuous function; the latter is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. At a minimum I would say that a function is the triple $(A,B,f)$ where $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain. There might be more structure depending on the structure of the domain and codomain.

Comment: In this triple, what is f? The relation?

Comment: @Lukas $f$ is the graph here, yes. Perhaps $f=(A,B,G)$ would be clearer nomenclature.

Comment: So this is actually saying that a function is a set (the _graph_) with certain properties with respect to two associated sets, which makes this definition dependent of three elements. This is why one would take a triple, correct?

Comment: @Lukas Provided there isn't too much additional structure, yes, that sounds right.

Comment: But could above conflict not be resolved by not saying “Let $f:=\{(x, x):x\in[0,1]\}$ be a set” but rather “Let $f:=\{(x, x):x\in[0,1]\}$ be a Function from $A$ to $B$”? In the last case, the set would indeed _be_ a continuous function whose elements are equal to those in the set describing the diagonal because we defined it as not just a set, but as a set with certain properties.

Comment: @Lukas That's not referentially transparent, which is a considerable philosophical problem.